# trying to create bootable usb with slax 32bit

Tags: boot

i'm trying to create a bootable usb with the .iso Slax 32 bit, but the startup disk creator that is included with Ubuntu doesn't want to accept the .iso.
what can i do?

Comment: You can write .iso directly to usb throw command line, like this:  `sudo dd bs=4M if=/patho/to/your/file.iso of=/dev/sdX conv=fdatasync` . Make sure that `/dev/sdX` is the driver of your usb. Youcan I also install `unetbootin` which is a nice graphicall interface to make LiveUSB of many available Linuxe falvors.

Answer (score 1):

### Standard advice

I tested cloning with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), and it does not work to boot from a cloned USB drive. The slax iso file

```
slax-64bit-9.11.0.iso
```

is *not* a hybrid iso file.

- The standard advice suggests that you need Windows or a second USB drive with FreeDOS or some other DOS version. Boot into FreeDOS and get into the `slax` directory on the slax drive and follow the instructions of `readme.txt` which includes running `bootinst.bat`.
- An alternative is to loop mount the iso file, create an empty FAT32 partition and copy the `slax` directory from the loop mount to the FAT32 file system. Then reboot into the drive with FreeDOS and follow the instructions of `readme.txt`.

### Create a hybrid iso file

I tested, and it works to turn the slax iso file into a hybrid iso file, and this makes things easy.

If the program `isohybrid` is not found, you can install it with the following program package

```
sudo apt install syslinux-utils
```

Run this copy command only to keep original iso file

```
cp -p slax.iso slax-hybrid.iso
```

The actual command to create a hybrid iso file

```
isohybrid slax-hybrid.iso
```

See `man isohybrid` for more details,

### Clone the hybrid iso file with mkusb (or any other cloning tool)

Now you can clone the `slax-hybrid.iso` file and get a bootable USB drive with slax.

Example if you use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb):

```
dus slax-hybrid.iso    # if you use mkusb
```